# How do I make a form_for select helper display dates in descending order?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to both Ruby and Rails and am having trouble getting a select drop down to show the current year first and then go back 30 years in descending order. I'm using form_for to generate the form/fields.

I can get it to work in ascending order with the following:

```
<%= builder.label :modelyear, "Model Year" %>        
<%= builder.select :modelyear, (Time.zone.now.year - 30)..(Time.zone.now.year + 0) %>
```

These do not work:

```
<%= builder.label :modelyear, "Model Year" %>        
<%= builder.select :modelyear, (Time.zone.now.year)..(Time.zone.now.year - 30) %>

<%= builder.label :modelyear, "Model Year" %>        
<%= builder.select :modelyear, (Time.zone.now.year + 0)..(Time.zone.now.year - 30) %>
```

**Edit: complete code as requested (with original attempt at selector)**

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
        <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

    <%= f.label :first_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
    <br /><br />

    <%= f.label :last_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
    <br /><br />

    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
    <br /><br />

    <%= f.label :address1 %>
    <%= f.text_field :address1 %>
    <br /><br />

    <%= f.label :address2 %>
    <%= f.text_field :address2 %>
    <br /><br />

    <%= f.label :city %>
    <%= f.text_field :city %>
    <br /><br />

    <%= f.label :state %>
    <%= f.text_field :state %>
    <br /><br />

    <%= f.label :zipcode %>
    <%= f.text_field :zipcode %>
    <br /><br />

    <%= f.label :country %>
    <%= f.text_field :country %>
    <br /><br />

    <!-- Fields For Product -->
    <%= f.fields_for :products do |builder| %>
    <div>
             <%= builder.label :serial, "Serial Number" %>        
             <%= builder.text_field :serial %>
             <br /><br />


             <%= builder.label :modelyear, "Model Year" %>        
             <%= builder.select :modelyear, (Time.zone.now.year - 30)..(Time.zone.now.year + 0) %>
             <br /><br />

 </div>
<% end %>

<%= f.submit "Register Your Product", class: "button" %>
```

**user.rb**

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :products, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :products, :allow_destroy => true
before_save { email.downcase! }
validates :first_name, presence: true
validates :last_name, presence: true
validates :email, presence: true
validates :address1, presence: true
validates :address2, length: { maximum: 30 }
validates :city, presence: true
validates :state, length: { maximum: 20 }
validates :zipcode, length: { maximum: 20 }
validates :country, presence: true
    end
```

**product.rb**

```
    class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
validates :serial, presence: true
validates :modelyear,     length: { maximum: 4 }
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
<%= builder.select :modelyear, ((Time.zone.now.year - 30)..(Time.zone.now.year + 0)).to_a.reverse %>
```

Here I am converting the `Range` object to an `Array`, which is also accepted by [select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select) as parameter. So you can use the convenient array [reverse](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/Array/reverse) method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%= builder.select :modelyear, Time.zone.now.year.downto(Time.zone.now.year - 30)
.to_a, class:'form-control' %>
```

Comment: I get an error trying to use a select_year method "undefined method `select_year' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:xxxxxxxx>"

Comment: I should mention my drop down is in a nested attributes/fields_for form. I don't know if that makes a difference.

Comment: I do not think that this should make difference. can you please show me your complete code?

Comment: Thanks Jiten. I've added it above.

Comment: create_table "products", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "modelyear"
  end

Comment: can you please show me the models, did you put nested_attributes_for on parent model???

Comment: i added them above. the form works fine. it writes to both the user and product tables successfully. I just can't get that select drop down to show descending years

Comment: descending years you mean 2014, 2013, 2012 all way to 30 years back?

Comment: that's exactly what i'm trying to do (or even being able to define a specific end date...not necessarily minus 30 years. it will always be current year - 1984)

Comment: Please check again, It is now working fine on my rails environment. it will show as 2014, 2013, 2012 all way to 1984 on Nested attributes. Sorry for delay as I was doing my project in between.

Comment: thanks so much! works beautifully. Now to figure out why it works! (thanks again. very much appreciated)

Comment: it is working because i have converted range to array.Can you please click on check mark as approved answer so i can get reputation points please?

Comment: I don't beleive this. You said my work beautifully and you checkmarked somebody else answer who just posted today. wow. I spend more then 45 mins on finding your answers alone.

Comment: I check marked both answers that were useful to me. Apologies if that's not how it's supposed to work. I am new to asking questions on Stack Overflow.